# How to set a global variable in jsp?

Tags: jsp

I am a newbie of jsp.
How to set a global variable in jsp?

I have two pages.

```
glob_var.jsp
index.jsp
```

glob_var.jsp content

```
<%!  
     int data=50;  
     String name = "Peter"; 
%>
```

index.jsp content

```
<body>
    <jsp:include page="glob_var.jsp"></jsp:include> 
    <%= "Value is:"+ data + "<br>" + "Name is:"+ name %> 
</body>
```

it gets Error
Unable to compile class for JSP:
data cannot be resolved to a variable

Any idea?? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the following code should be working properly.

```
<%@include file="glob_var.jsp" %>
<body>
    <%= "Value is:"+ data + "<br>" + "Name is:"+ name %> 
</body>
```